# How to reshape a tensor to the shape of a placeholder?

Tags: tensorflow

How to reshape a tensor to the shape of a placeholder?

```
a = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, 48])
h, w, c = a.shape
b = tf.reshape(a, shape=[-1, 4, 4, 3]) # flatten the first two dimension and expand the last dimension
# do something
c = tf.reshape(b, shape=[h, w, 3]) # reshape back to the shape of a, but error occurs
```

I want to reshpae tensor `b` back to the shape of placeholder `a`.

Comment: This doesn't work since `a` has two undefined dimensions, meaning reshaping to its static shape is not uniquely defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` has dynamic shapes that are not known at graph construction time, so you need to turn to tensorflow operations, and more specifically to `tf.shape` that returns (dynamically) the shape of a tensor.

So in your example you could use e.g.

```
s = tf.shape(a)
c = tf.reshape(b, shape=[s[0], s[1], 3])
```

Comment: Wow, it works! I think the document of Tensorflow should have an emphasis on the concept of "static" and "dynamic".